# ( Naive question )How to show a set is dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How to show a set is dense ?

Is there any easy technique to follow ?

How to show a set is dense in real line?  Can I show a set is dense in the real line by showing every open  interval  (a,b)  has  non  empty intersection?

How to show rational number is dense in (0,1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you show that a set $D$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ by showing every open interval $(a,b)$ has non empty intersection with $D$. In particular, since every open interval of real numbers contains some rational number, $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you. I am so dumb.

Comment: No, you are not dumb. And if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I already did but my reputation is too low to do that. Only user with reputation higher than 15 can mark answer as a useful one.

Comment: You are wrong. You need 15 points of reputation to *upvote* an answer. I am suggesting that you *accept* my answer, and you can do that with *any* reputation. Just click the ✓ sign. And you will gain 2 reputation points.